# Chrome - how to send a shortcut to the desktop?

Tags: google-chrome

When viewing a web page, Internet Explorer has the simple option of sending a shortcut to the desktop (*File > Send > Shortcut to desktop*). Clicking the shortcut will open the same page complete with an address bar.

Is there a way to make Chrome do exactly the same thing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides Harrymc's answer, you can directly create a shortcut on the desktop be clicking the settings menu (3 vertical dots) and click "Create Shortcut."  This will place a shortcut directly on the Window's Desktop.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for.  I have to add the 'More Tools' step in the middle though, like this: Settings menu > More Tools > Create Shortcut.

Comment: @Hegehog well if thats the answer mark it and vote it up

Comment: I thought I already had (I'm not familiar with how this website works).  Just done it now.

Answer (score 1):

Drag the icon to the left of the address-bar to the desktop.

The shortcut will be to the website, so it will open Chrome if it's defined
as the default browser.

[image]

Comment: That works well if Chrome's window isn't maximised - it's a bit trickier if it is though.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Step by step instructions for Chrome]

- Step 1: Top right corner, press the 'Three Dots' button for more
  settings.
- Step 2: Select 'More Tools'
- Step 3: Select 'Create Shortcut'

Chrome version: Version 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit) as of 5/25/2021

Comment: Ok, thanks for the screengrab and details. I'm on the same version of Chrome.